# How to increase the space between post content & post labels in Blogger?

Tags: html, css, blogs, blogger, blogspot

How do I increase the space between post content & post labels in Blogger? Here's a screenshot from my blog to make it clear:

[image: A screenshot of my blog]

I know it can be done by an HTML/CSS code, but I don't know what it is.

I am using the Awesome Inc template.

Comment: It all depends on the theme you are using. Please post your blog address so we could help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's a private blog so I can't make it public. As for the theme, I'm using Awesome Inc. template if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one in "Theme > Customise > Advanced > Add CSS" section on your blog dashboard:

```
.post-footer { margin-top: 45px }
```